# In Chrome Dev Tools, how do I see where my HTML is saved?

Tags: html

I've updated a site's index.html, but I'm not seeing any updates on the site. I've refreshed, cleared cache, used another device and another browser, but I'm just getting the old site.

I'm worried it's because I've updated the wrong file, and it's actually not using index.html as a homepage. Is this possible? How do I see what page is the home page?

Thanks

Comment: Chrome cannot tell you what *file* something is in, only what *URL* it loaded contents from. What file on disk that corresponds to is entirely arbitrary and up to the particular web server configuration.

Comment: As a sort of proof of what deceze is saying, think about Rails -- the _files_ need not have anything to do with the _URLs_. All that matters is how the server chooses to respond to a given URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome's Dev Tools (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`I`), you should be able to see the page's Html under the elements menu. To view the source, you can click on the sources tab or press `Ctrl`+`U`. If you are using a website like Github to host your webpage, it might take some time for the index.html to update on the server, so be patient. Just wait a little while and if you can still see the old Html, then make sure you updated the right file. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! It's just giving me 'http://my sites nomal url' as the source. Is this normal? I updated the HTML in the hosting cPanel and usually I find it's pretty immediate if the cache is cleared? Or am i being paranoid and this is normal? Thank you

Comment: If you are using view-source, then seeing your site's normal url is normal. Can you provide a link to your site?

Comment: No problem, the website should update eventually as long as you updated the right file :)

Comment: thanks v much, deleting my prev comment to hide my site :)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome Dev Tools doesn't update any local files, it only changes the document as-loaded into your browser. Your changes are not saved and they are lost when you reload the page.

Note that Chrome Dev Tools does have a Local Workspace option, which does allow for this functionality, but you have to enable and configure it:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow

> To make a local folder's source files editable in the Sources panel:
>
> 1. Right-click in the left-side panel.
> 2. Select Add Folder to Workspace.
> 3. Choose location of local folder that you want to map.
> 4. Click Allow to give Chrome access to the folder.

Comment: Thank you, but I understand that! What I am asking is if Dev Tools can show me where to find the correct file to update my site, as it doesn't seem to be the index.html file in the public_html directory.